# Ionic cordova camera plugin crashes intermittently after a picture is taken (with Firebase image upload)

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

```
uploadImage(filePath: string, camera: boolean = false) {
try {
  let options: CameraOptions;
  if (camera) {
    options = {
      quality: 40,
      destinationType: this._camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this._camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this._camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      correctOrientation: true
    }
  } else {
    options = {
      destinationType: this._camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: this._camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      encodingType: this._camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this._camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }
  }

  this._camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
    const photo = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${imageData}`;
    const fileRef = this._afs.ref(filePath);
    const task = fileRef.putString(photo, 'data_url');

    task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        // execute other actions
        fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe(url => {
          if (url) {
            this.fileUploadUrl.next(url);
          }
        })
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'Image upload successfully',
          position: 'bottom',
          duration: 3000
        });
        toast.present();
      })
    ).subscribe();
  })

} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
  let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: 'Image upload cancelled',
    position: 'bottom',
    duration: 3000
  });
  toast.present();
}
```

}

After a picture a taken (from actual iOS device) sometimes it crashes, sometimes it works fine. If I use the front camera, it always work.
But if I use the back camera, after a picture a selected, it flashes a white screen and then the app restarts. I suspect if it’s something to do with the image size or resolution. Sometimes if I take a very low res picture with the back camera (like in a low light environment), it uploads just fine. I researched a bit online, some people suggest running the app with production mode with `--prod` flag, but it is not solving it.
I also tried to lower the quality value to a lower number, but that still doesn’t work with the back camera.

I am pretty sure the plugin is added correctly and the privacy settings are also correct otherwise it won't allow me to take pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. When taking picture using camera with DataURL (i.e Base64). we may face memory issue because of the picture size and quality. You have quality of '40' with is fine. For Width and height you can set around 300px.

The more the image size will increase the size of the image which will impact the memory.

Comment: I also tried just using FILE_URI instead of DATA_URL, but it still crashes when taking a picture from the back camera.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately.

Comment: Then it should be issue with your phone memory. Try to validate in another Phone that has good memory

Answer (score 0):

It's not the proper solution for your query, but after wasting my nights on the same I tried to reduce the image and tried to maintain it less than 2mb and it worked quite well.You can reduce the image size by giving the targetWidth and targetHeight. I kept both of them below 500.

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 30, // picture quality
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      cameraDirection: this.camera.Direction.FRONT,
      allowEdit: true,
      correctOrientation    :false,
      targetWidth: 400,
      targetHeight: 400,
    }
```